# Windows 10 wants to format FAT32 partition

Tags: windows-10, fat32

I've an USB-stick with one FAT32 partition. The files in one specific folder caused Windows 10 to notify me about damaged files, so I plugged that USB-stick in my desktop running Debian Unstable. I mounted it and wanted to remove that folder, but I found out it was mounted as read-only, because it was damaged, so I ran `fsck`. After that, it was mounted normally, so I removed that folder. Then I put my USB-stick back in my Windows 10 laptop, which said I needed to format that partition, so I put it back in my desktop to check if it's still working, which it did. How could I get Windows 10 to be able to read that partition again? I don't want to format it.

[image: Screenshot of GParted]

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the filesystem type? If not, fsck assumes the filesystem is ext2. The USB has since been repaired to work on the ext2 filesystem (don't know how this was achieved), and it's unlikely you'll be able to use it on Windows again without completely formatting it into a support Windows filesystem (like FAT32 or NTFS).

Comment: Yes, I did specify a filesystem type.

Comment: Have you checked what the filesystem type of the USB is listed as on your Debian machine?

Comment: It's still FAT32.

Comment: I dunno what else to do then... You could try checking what the partition table is using gparted on debian - fsck may have changed the partition table type.

Comment: The partition table is just MSDOS.

Comment: huh... fat32, and msdos. it SHOULD be reading, so I really don't know what else apart from full format on Windows.